# WM_CREATE return value

Tags: c, winapi

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) WM_CREATE should return `0` or `-1`. I analyze a code where `WM_CREATE` returns `TRUE`:

```
return TRUE; //TRUE translates to 1: #define TRUE 1
             //TRUE is defined in minwindef.h
```

Is it a bug in the code or returning TRUE is allowed and has some meaning ?

Comment: Please post the code. `(bool)-1` gives true for example.

Comment: What numeric value does `TRUE` have or translate to in the language you're writing code in? If it is not -1, then yes, that can be considered a bug.

Comment: `#define TRUE 1`

Comment: `TRUE` is defined in minwindef.h

Comment: Always follow the convention: `FALSE` is zero, `TRUE` is non-zero.  Never assume that a "true" value is equal to any specific number. -1 is true, and so is 1, and 42.

Comment: This is a bug. `TRUE` is not a valid return value for `WM_CREATE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0 and -1 are the only documented values you can return when processing `WM_CREATE`. Most likely anything other than -1 is treated as success but the code is technically broken and should be changed to `return 0`.

What most likely happened is that someone looked at `WM_INITDIALOG` where `TRUE` is a valid return value.

Comment: (Or someone looked at code with `HANDLE_MSG`  message-cracker macros from `<windowsx.h>`, where the `WM_CREATE` message is passed to a function that should return `TRUE` for success and `FALSE` for failure.)